# very odd jquery/asp.net webforms textarea max length

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

Using `www.lipsum.com` to generate 2,000 chars, check the character count within word and there is 2,000 chars.

With ASP WebForms, I have the following control:

```
<asp:textbox runat="server" ID="txtComment" rows="5"  TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="form-control" />
```

Then, a bit of jQuery to set the limit to 2000 chars:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('#<%=txtComment.ClientID%>').prop('maxlength', 2000);
})
```

When I paste the 2000 chars into the textarea, the last 6 characters aren't being pasted over.

Next step, I added the following line to check the pasted text character count:

```
alert($('#<%=txtComment.ClientID%>').val().length);
```

This returns 2000.

Copy and paste from the textbox back into word and the word count is 1994.

What am I missing?

Comment: so, how many new lines do you have there + non-visible characters?

Comment: Also, if you have any special characters or characters from some languages, this can make some characters count as 2. Got this issue since I work with english and french, and a `é` is counted as 2 characters if I remember correctly.

Comment: You can use a tool such as Notepad++ to view tabs and spaces. Use the View menu —> View Symbol —> Show White Space and Tab. Probably combination of spaces and line return and carriage feed that’s getting trimmed

Answer (score 0):

thanks to  Icepickle

carriage i had two carriage returns remove them and it was as expected